# ggpubr -> ggline plot: not able to reproduce examples with multiple factors

Tags: r, plot, errorbar, ggpubr

I have the feeling that R is not working properly on my system.

I want to use an interaction plot to present my two-way ANOVA results. So I used the package ggpubr and am plotting with ggline using the example with multiple factors.
It did not show the errorbars properly, instead of showing them for each factor, it grouped the factors, and the bars also appear black (see pictures below).

So I tested it with the exact example as in the package description (http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/79-plot-meansmedians-and-error-bars):

```
library(ggpubr)    
ggline(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
           add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),
           color = "supp", palette = "jco")
```

Which SHOULD give me this graph:

[image: Graph from working example]

However, on my system I get this:

[image: Graph on my system]

I already:

- updated the ggpubr package and all other packages
- completely re-installed R from scratch
- asked the package developer, it seems to be no package-bug cause it
  works for him

Can someone reproduce the same problem? I really don't know how to solve it and I also get the feeling that R might mess up other graphs as well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Same here. I see the same problem with R 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) and ggpubr 0.1.8 (2018-08-30). The "mean_se" was not properly grouped.

Comment: This has been fixed in the development version, as indicated in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/109).  What that means is the CRAN version still has the bug but the most recent GitHub version does not.  You can install from GitHub via `devtools::install_github("kassambara/ggpubr")`.  I just updated to this and, indeed, the problem appears to be fixed.

Comment: @aosmith the dev version indeed fixed the bug. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that the updated version is producing the correct graph. Thanks a lot for this fast support on this. Awesome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ggline(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len", 
       add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),
       color = "supp", add.params = list(group="supp"), palette = "jco")
```